# Get temperature by getElementsByClassName convert to celsius replace original temperature

Tags: javascript, temperature

Temperature is pulled in from xml. I need to convert this number after the page loads and replace the original number.

```
<td class="weathertemperature temperatureplus">26</td>

function convert() {
      F = document.getElementsByClassName("weathertemperature").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    document.getElementsByClassName("weathertemperature").value = Math.round(F);

}
convert();
```

when I debug alert(F); I get NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements that you must access by index, like you do with an array.

Because the collection itself has no `.value`, you get `NaN` when using it in a mathematical operation.

If you only want the first one, use `[0]` to get the first match, or just use `.querySelector` with a CSS selector.

```
function convert() {
   var wt = document.querySelector(".weathertemperature");
   wt.value = Math.round(wt.value * 9 / 5 + 32);
}
convert();
```

If you want to operate on multiple, use a loop like you'd do with any other array-like collection.

Also, you're using `.value` on a `<td>` element. Not sure why. The `.value` property is mainly for form controls. Did you mean `.textContent`?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, so you have to loop over them to set new temperature to all of them.

You can pass the element collection into the function and loop over them in there.

```js
function convert(items) {
  for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    items[i].innerText = Math.round(items[i].innerText * 9 / 5 + 32);
  }
}

convert(document.getElementsByClassName("weathertemperature"));
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="weathertemperature temperatureplus">26</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td class="weathertemperature temperatureplus">28</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have different conversions to make, you can pass that in as an argument as well or rename the function.